# Play scala template with google Multimap

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.0, multimap

I have a Multimap object from com.google.common.collect.Multimap.
How can i iterate throught this Multimap in my Play scala template ?

@if(!googleMultimapObject.isEmpty()){

for ...

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import JavaConverters at the top of your template (i.e. second line, not the signature)

```
@import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

This will supply `asScala` methods to your java collections. via an implicit.

Now you can do this:

```
@for(entry <- googleMultimapObject.entries.asScala) {
  <p>@entry.getKey()</p>
  <p>@entry.getValue()</p>
}
```

Alternatively, to list the values for each key, you can do this:

```
@for((key, values) <- googleMultimapObject.asMap.asScala) {
  <p>key: @key</p>
  <p>
  @for (value <- values.asScala) {
    <span>@value</span>
  }
  </p>
}
```

There's a shortcut happening here to unpack the key and values: `.asMap.asScala` gives us a scala map. When you iterate a scala map, you get tuples of `(KeyType, ValueType)`. The above syntax unpacks the tuple into `(key, values)`

Comment: how can i do if i want to iterate first for the key and next for the values like this in Java :                              for (Map.Entry<String,Collection<Job>> entry : listOfJobByModel.asMap().entrySet())
                {Collection<Object> jCollection = entry.getValue();
                    }

Comment: @user3669225 I updated my answer -- is that what you had in mind? (BTW, you should delete your answer, better to ask for clarification in a comment. Welcome to Stack Overflow!)